# Objective C - Setting a variable in viewDidLoad and using it elsewhere

Tags: iphone, objective-c, variables, viewdidload

another objective c question for you. Probably a simple one too...

In my viewDidLoad method I am setting a variable. I need to access this within `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` however I am receivig the following error and I don't really know a way to sort it!

**-[CFString intValue]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x592dcb0**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    //code to get json is here
    totalInCategory = [parsedJson objectForKey:@"TotalInCategory"];
    NSLog(@"totalincat %i",[totalInCategory intValue]);

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)celllforRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"totalincat %i",[totalInCategory intValue]);

    if((indexPath.row == [myArray count]-1)&&(indexPath.row < [totalInCategory intValue]))
    {
        //code to get more rows
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

I have NSString *totalInCategory; set up and synthesized.

totalInCategory is fine within viewDidLoad (as far as I'm aware that is), but nowhere else... any ideas would be really handy!

Comment: have you release totalInCategory in between ?

Comment: No, it's autoreleased, see my answer.

Comment: @iAmitWagh Nope, hence the confusion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retain the data...

```
totalInCategory = [[parsedJson objectForKey:@"TotalInCategory"] retain];
```

objectForKey returns an autoreleased object which you need to retain if you wish to use it. Don't forget to add a `[totalInCategory release];` in the dealloc.

Answer (score 2):

put:

`[totalInCategory retain]` just below `totalInCategory = [parsedJson objectForKey:@"TotalInCategory"];`

That will retain the variable, which is currently autoreleased by the `objectForKey` method.

Comment: Yep this and the reply below by @SimonLee did it, though which way is best (if either)?

Comment: They do the same thing... my version is more concise but either is good.

Comment: Ah cool, I used yours :) Many thanks indeed, now to fix he other problem that doing this has generated... bah!

Comment: Its more consise, and is probably a bit more readable, however neither is "better" really. They're both doing exactly the same thing. `totalInCategory` is just a reference for `[parsedJson objectForKey:@"TotalInCategory"]` effectively. Whether you retain the former or the latter doesn't matter. They're the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the type of parsedJson I can't be sure, but it seems likely that you're missing a retain.

```
 totalInCategory = [[parsedJson objectForKey:@"TotalInCategory"] retain];
```

And in the dealloc method for the class add

```
 [totalInCategory release];
```

You should probably also take a glance at the iOS [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Use `totalInCategory` with `self`. if you have specified **retain** in the property declaration .

```
self.totalInCategory = [parsedJson objectForKey:@"TotalInCategory"];
```

Comment: You are making the assumption that a) totalInCategory is a property and b) that it has the retain attribute.

Comment: I agree but without stipulating those assumptions or suggesting adding an @property etc it could be a bit misleading. :)